# Unexpected Shutdown mongos version v4.2.0

Tags: mongodb

I'm facing a problem in a PROD server. 3 Mongos nodes was unexpectedly shutdown.
This is a message in the log file when the node down.

```
[conn132492] operation was interrupted because a client disconnected
[conn132492] terminate() called. No exception is active 0x5620c0615da1 0x5620c0615b58 0x5620c0720386 0x5620c07203c1 0x5620bf8a29ad 0x5620bfb1c5f9 0x5620bfb1cb72 0x5620bfa41f28 0x5620bfa6540c 0x5620bfa5f80f 0x5620bfa62a8c 0x5620bfdca2f2 0x5620bfa5d22d 0x5620bfa604c3 0x5620bfa5e8f7 0x5620bfa5f76b 0x5620bfa62a8c 0x5620bfdca75b 0x5620c04bcc64 0x7f4a7735cdd5 0x7f4a77085ead
```

How do I know the root cause of this issue?
Could anyone help and suggest?

Thank you

Comment: upgrade to version v4.2.1

Comment: Thank you mehta-rohan.
Why does the version v4.2.1 help? or is this a bug in v4.2.0?

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest patch release in 4.2 series which is currently 4.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade to version v4.2.1+.

There is a bug in this version.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is fixed in 4.2.7.

Know more at here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-47553